# Convert rads to degrees and return absolute value for 360

Tags: javascript

How do I convert rads to degrees and return absolute value for 360 degrees.  That is, once it gets past 180 it continues to 359, then to 0.

The following returns positive degrees, but only in the 180 range.

```
console.log(Math.abs(rads * (180/Math.PI)));
```

The purpose for this is that I want to return numbers in a compass up to 360 degrees, and not show negative numbers.

Comment: @iIlludiumPu36 Mate, In your code taking absolute, isn't changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to use negative values for angles.

```js
const rads = 8;
console.log(Math.abs(360- rads * (180/Math.PI)))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This returns the result I'm wanting rads * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
rads * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180
```